# Rewriting summation expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $i=1,...,n$. We have $$s_i-\frac{5}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}s_j=\bigg[\frac{n-5}{n}\bigg]s_i-\frac{5}{n}\sum_{j\neq i}s_j.$$

I am not sure why $s_i+\sum_{j\neq i} s_j=\sum_{j=1}^{n} s_j$ is true.

Is it because $\sum_{j=1}^{n} s_j=s_1+s_2+...+s_n=s_i+s_j$ for $i=1$ and $j=2,...,n$?

That is, in summation notation $s_i+s_j=s_i+\sum_{j\neq i} s_j$.

I'd appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $s_j$ is defined for $j=1,2,\ldots, n$ where $n$ is a positive integer.  It is always true that for any $i\in\{1,2\ldots, n\}$, 
$$s_i+ \sum_{j\ne i}s_j=s_i+ \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}s_j+\sum_{j=i+1}^ns_j$$
$$=s_i+ s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_{i-1}+s_{i+1}+s_{i+2}+\cdots+s_n= \sum_{j=1}^n s_j.
$$  This is true because either $j=i$ or $j\ne i$.

Maybe an example would help.  Let's suppose that $s_i$ is only defined for $i=1,2,$ and $3$.  Let $s_1=2$, $s_2=20$, and $s_3=7.$ (I just chose three random values for the $s_j$.)

Now if $i=2$, then $\sum_{j\ne i}= s_1+s_3 = 2 + 7 = 9$.  Also, $\sum_{\hskip{0.2mm}j=1}^3 s_j= s_1+s_2+s_3 = 2 +20+ 7 = 29$.  And 
$$
s_i+ \sum_{j\ne i}s_j= s_i + s_1+s_3 = s_2 + s_1 + s_3 = \sum_{j=1}^3 s_j.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $i=1,2,...,n$ and $j=1,2,...,n$.

So $\sum_{j=1}^n s_j=s_i+\sum_{j\neq i}s_j$ means that the summation of all elements $s_1,s_2,...,s_{i-1},s_i,s_{i+1},...,s_n$ is the same as $s_i$ plus the summation of all elements in $s_1,s_2,...,s_{i-1},s_{i+1},...,s_n$.

Note that in the second case I am considering the subindices $j=1,..,i-1,i+1,...n$.